# Storing MySQL query as function

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm new to MySQL functions. I Created a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `tems`.`<function_name>`(IN bid INT, IN cid INT)
RETURNS INT(10)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE min_no INT;
SELECT COALESCE(min(number),1)
FROM
  (SELECT r1.number -1 AS number, r1.branch_id, r1.course_id
  FROM `Room` AS r1
  LEFT JOIN `Room` AS r2
    ON r1.branch_id = r2.branch_id 
      AND r1.course_id = r2.course_id
      AND (r1.number - 1) = r2.number
  WHERE r1.number > 1 AND r2.number IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT max(number) + 1, branch_id, course_id
  FROM `Room`
  GROUP BY branch_id, course_id) AS q
WHERE branch_id=bid AND course_id=cid
GROUP BY branch_id, course_id
INTO min_no;
RETURN (min_no);
END;
```

And I want to get `bid`, `cid` and return the select value, but I'm getting an error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN bid INT, IN cid INT)
RETURNS INT(10)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS ' at line 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code with the error is not included in your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry. updated

Comment: Get your query to run on it's own before you put it into a function.

Comment: @DanBracuk query works

Comment: YOu dont need the table name in there just use a single name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `DELIMITER` like below along with removing the two part identifier. Just declare the function name.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION MyTestFunc (bid INT, cid INT)
RETURNS INT(10)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE min_no INT;
SELECT COALESCE(min(number),1)
FROM
  (SELECT r1.number -1 AS number, r1.branch_id, r1.course_id
  FROM `Room` AS r1
  LEFT JOIN `Room` AS r2
    ON r1.branch_id = r2.branch_id 
      AND r1.course_id = r2.course_id
      AND (r1.number - 1) = r2.number
  WHERE r1.number > 1 AND r2.number IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT max(number) + 1, branch_id, course_id
  FROM `Room`
  GROUP BY branch_id, course_id) AS q
WHERE branch_id=bid AND course_id=cid
GROUP BY branch_id, course_id
INTO min_no;
RETURN (min_no);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN bid INT, IN cid INT)
RETURNS INT(10)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS ' at line 1

Comment: @demonoid, refresh your page and check the edited one. Remove the table name before function name.

Comment: @demonoid, strange but remove those `IN` before parameters. See edit in answer.